# local tracks returned as null by Spotify WEB API

Tags: spotify

When a local track is in a playlist, WEB API returns track URI as `spotify:track:null`

I would expect to have it in same format as in Spotify desktop app, i.e:  `spotify:local:ARTIST:ALBUM:TRACK:LENGTH_IN_SECONDS`

The use case is (github page https://github.com/vdesabou/alfred-spotify-mini-player):
-Get the user library into a local sqlite DB
-Get a track from the DB and play it with AppleScript

With the URI returned, the local track cannot be played at all. Why is Web API retuning null ?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, this is a known issue and it's hopefully going to be fixed soon.

Comment: Great, I'm really looking forward to the fix. Any chance to have a list of Known issues on the Web Api documentation site? That would help.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll bring it up with the rest of the team.